# What is a word that means "Appreciative of Creativity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was trying to think of a word to replace "appreciative of creativity" in the sentence below:

> Hipsters are young, independent, deviant from social norms, and appreciative of creativity.

Please note that I am trying to distinguish that they may not possess any creativity, but they value it.

Comment: Deviants - plural- and “appreciative of creativity* seems to work and flows nicely.  What’s wrong with it?

Comment: I find that creativity is rarely appreciated.  Certainly not often enough to merit its own word.

Comment: Like Jim, I'd use "deviants," and a possible change would be to end with "...and value creativity."

Comment: @Jim Isn't _deviant_ an adjective + preposition here, following parallel structure?

Comment: "Hipsters are young [sic], independent [sic], socially deviant neophiliacs."

Comment: @JEL I read "neophiliacs" as "necrophiliacs" on first (and maybe second) glance, that might be a common error I think.

Comment: In terms of cuisine./cooking, such people are called **epicures**. I'll look for a more general term.

Comment: @MaxWilliams necrophiliacs have sexual attraction to corpses. Neophiliacs are forward-thinking.

Comment: @EthanLeyden very good.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could find is the word "[aesthete](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aesthete)" meaning a person who is appreciative of and sensitive to art and beauty.

Comment: So in this sentence, we could say that "Hipsters are...aesthetes."

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

***open-minded***, defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/open-minded) as:

> Receptive to new and different ideas or the opinions of others.

People who appreciate creativity are, almost by definition, open-minded.  However, people who are open-minded might also appreciate a lot of what turns out to be not true.

I want to avoid art and politics in my example, so I'll choose three examples from  physics:  (1) [polywater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywater); (2) [cold fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_fusion); (3) [neutrinos going faster than the speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light_neutrino_anomaly).

In each case, the phenomenon, which if true, would have been revolutionary,   was found not to exist.  However, physicists were excited; physicists wanted the apple cart to be upset, because in physics, upset apple carts lead to great progress.  Thus, they were **open-minded** about three potential revolutions that proved to be experimental errors.

As far as hipsters, which was what you were asking about, open-minded hipsters are likely to appreciate not only creativity, but also what turns out to be nonsense.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not what I am looking for. Open-minded is often interpreted as being highly "receptive" to new ideas, which differs from being "appreciative," which in this case is being used to mean, "recognition" for a talent/ability. What I am looking for is a word to represent the act of "recognizing" an idea, talent, or ability. To sum it up, the difference between open-minded and appreciative in this case is not entirely unlike the difference between "receptive" and "recognizing."

Comment: @Ethan Leyden OK, I understand open-minded not being right for you.  Other possibilities are: perceptive, critic, connoisseur, but I need to pay real life some attention now.